# Does `#[account(init)]` create a PDA account or a non-PDA account?

Tags: anchor, pda

1. Does the below declaration mean to create a PDA account?

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreatePixel<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer=user, space=Pixel::LEN)]
    pub pixel: Account<'info, Pixel>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

2. Or must I use 'seeds' to create PDA a account？ No matter the seeds' value, is even "" (empty) acceptable?

```
// Data validators
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateCounter<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    authority: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [],
        bump,
        payer = authority,
        space = 100
    )]
    counter: Account<'info, Counter>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does bellow declare mean to create a PDA account?
>
> ```
> pub struct CreatePixel<'info> {
>    #[account(init, payer=user, space=Pixel::LEN)]
>    pub pixel: Account<'info, Pixel>,
>    #[account(mut)]
>    pub user: Signer<'info>,
>    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
> }
> ```

No, the `init` constraint without seeds and bump doesn't create the PDA account. It will mark the account as a signer and expect you to provide the signature while calling the instruction.

> or must I use 'seeds' to create PDA account？ no matter the seeds value, even "" empty is acceptable?

This is correct! You must use both `seeds` and `bump` constraints to initialize a PDA account. Seed is a byte-array so empty array is also a valid seed.

Comment: Got it. Thanks very much.